# Ajax not updating to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysql

So I'm having a bit of difficulty getting user input to post to my database.

Whenever I try to update the table, I am able to do it successfully on the front end, but on refresh, the data change does not stick. Checking the database further verifies that the data has not been changed... It seems like the "success" is passing in the AJAX, but for some reason, it's not updating the database.

In fact, for my HTTP request, Chrome tells me that my POST request is being processed as a GET request for some reason and I'm not sure why...

**JS**:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".edit_tr").click(function () {
    var commitID = $(this).attr('id');
    // on click, hide the text
    $("#name_"+commitID).hide();
    $("#created_"+commitID).hide();
    $("#status_"+commitID).hide();
    $("#disbanded_"+commitID).hide();

    // on click, show the input fields for editing
    $("#name_input_"+commitID).show();
    $("#created_input_"+commitID).show();
    $("#status_input_"+commitID).show();
    $("#disbanded_input_"+commitID).show();
  }).change(function() {
    var commitID = $(this).attr('id');
    var name = $("#name_input_"+commitID).val();
    var date_created = $("#created_input_"+commitID).val();
    var status = $("#status_input_"+commitID).val();
    var disbanded = $("#disbanded_input_"+commitID).val();
    var dataString = {
     id: commitID,
     name: name,
     date_created: date_created,
     status: status,
     disbanded: disbanded
    };

    console.log(dataString);
    // can place loading image here

    jQuery.post({
      url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      data: dataString,
      action: 'editCommittee',
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
      },
      success: function (response) {
        $("#name_"+commitID).html(name);
        $("#created_"+commitID).html(date_created);
        $("#status_"+commitID).html(status);
        $("#disbanded_"+commitID).html(disbanded);
        console.log("Got this from server: " + response);
        console.log("This is what happened to data: ");
        console.dir(dataString);
      }
    });
});
```

**functions.php**:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_editCommittee', 'editCommittee');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_editCommittee', 'editCommittee');

function editCommittee() {
  global $wpdb;

    if($_POST['id']) {
      $id = esc_sql($_POST['id']);
      $name = esc_sql($_POST['name']);
      $created = esc_sql($_POST['date_created']);
      $status = esc_sql($_POST['status']);
      $disbanded = esc_sql($_POST['disbanded']);

      $wpdb->update('wp_committees',
                    array(
                        'name' => $name
                    ),

                    array(
                        'committee_id' => $id
                    ),

                    array(
                      '%s'
                    )
      );
      exit;
    }
}
```

My data on the front end is being printed out into a table, so I don't have a form... Any insight on this would be helpful!

**Edit:**

`var_dump($_REQUEST);` on the page that is outputting the data in the table gives `array(0){}`twelve times-- the same number of items that I'm printing in the table.

`var_dump($_REQUEST);` on **functions.php** doesn't print anything

`console.log(response)` on **JS** file prints `0`.

Regardless if I put `var_dump($_REQUEST)` in the if statement (before `$wpdb->update`) or before the if statement, nothing gets printed.

**Edit 2:**

```
function getAjax() {
  wp_register_script('ajax_url_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/edit.js', array('jQuery'));
  wp_localize_script( 'ajax_url_script', 'postAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_url_script');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'getAjax' );
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_REQUEST);` then `console.log(response);` in your JS?

Comment: `var_dump($_REQUEST);` on the page that is outputting data gives me `array(0) { }` twelve times-- the exact number of items I'm printing in the table. 

`var_dump($_REQUEST)` on **functions.php** doesn't print anything. `console.log(response)` on **JS** file prints `0`.

Comment: No, I would throw that in before you `$wpdb->update` to see the data that is trying to into the DB. And log it in JS. You can post in your question because it's hard to read as a comment. Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that! I've updated my post with the information I mentioned before and with what happens if I put `var_dump($_REQUEST)` before `$wpdb->update`. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: The `exit` is in the `if` statement. Put the `exit` at the bottom of the function and put the var dump there. It looks like `id` isn't coming through. `0` usually shows up when you haven't handled the function properly.

Comment: Does is matter if you throw the `action: 'editCommittee',` inside the `data: dataString,`?

Comment: I put `exit` at the bottom and put var dump in its old place-- no printed output. Nope, doesn't matter if I put `action: 'editCommittee' inside the `dataString` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test your AJAX is working

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_editCommittee', 'test_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_editCommittee', 'test_ajax_request' );
function test_ajax_request() {

    echo "Request: " . PHP_EOL;

    var_dump( $_REQUEST );

    exit;
}
```

And update your request to move the `action` into the `data` sent:

```
jQuery (document).ready (function($) {


    $ (".edit_tr").click (function() {


        var commitID = $ (this).attr ('id');

        // on click, hide the text
        $ ("#name_" + commitID).hide ();
        $ ("#created_" + commitID).hide ();
        $ ("#status_" + commitID).hide ();
        $ ("#disbanded_" + commitID).hide ();

        // on click, show the input fields for editing
        $ ("#name_input_" + commitID).show ();
        $ ("#created_input_" + commitID).show ();
        $ ("#status_input_" + commitID).show ();
        $ ("#disbanded_input_" + commitID).show ();

    }).change (function() {

        var commitID = $ (this).attr ('id');
        var name = $ ("#name_input_" + commitID).val ();
        var date_created = $ ("#created_input_" + commitID).val ();
        var status = $ ("#status_input_" + commitID).val ();
        var disbanded = $ ("#disbanded_input_" + commitID).val ();
        var dataString = {
            action: 'editCommittee',
            id: commitID,
            name: name,
            date_created: date_created,
            status: status,
            disbanded: disbanded
        };

        console.log (dataString);
        // can place loading image here

        $.ajax({
            type : "post", 
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: dataString, 
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval ("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert (err.Message);
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $ ("#name_" + commitID).html (name);
                $ ("#created_" + commitID).html (date_created);
                $ ("#status_" + commitID).html (status);
                $ ("#disbanded_" + commitID).html (disbanded);
                console.log ("Got this from server: " + response);
                console.log ("This is what happened to data: ");
                console.dir (dataString);
            }
        });
    });
```

I you still don't get anything it's probably your URL. You can try to localize the `admin-ajax.php` URL like this answer shows:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22007593/5623301

Comment: Yep, still nothing. So localize `admin-ajax.php` like **Edit 2:** above and place in **functions.php**?

Comment: It keeps says `postAjax` is undefined... any ideas?

Comment: You didn't do it correctly. If you localize the script, which mean just printing the variables before the JS script, then you should have access to it. Perhaps you need to use an admin hook like - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Comment: I just fixed it! It turns out that it wasn't processing it because I used **jQuery** instead of **jquery**

Comment: Nice! glad you fixed it.